# Jquery textcomplete div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi everyone i have one question about jquery textcomplete.

I think this is easy but i don't know how can i do that.

I created this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/nzbb8zf1/)** without jquery

So what is my question. I want when i write in textarea open parenthesis `(` then `.textBox` div automatically open.

How can i do that anyone can tell me?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="textarea_wrap">
        <textarea id="textarea" class="text"></textarea>
        <div class="tagBox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .container{
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        margin:0px auto;
        margin-top:30px;
    }
    .textarea_wrap{
        width:100%;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        position:relative;
    }
    .text{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        outline:none;
        border:1px solid #999999;
    }
    .tagBox{
        width:300px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;
        display:none;
    }
```

Comment: What you mean by **automatically open**, there's nothing close in your example?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I mean when you write open paranthesis the .texBox will open like hashtag system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzbb8zf1/5/) **Using regex instead of several conditions** :

**JS :**

```
 $(function(){
    $('#textarea').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().match(/([(]$)/g)){
            $('.tagBox').show();
        }else{
            $('.tagBox').hide();    
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: i have check your fiddle , but it want work if your write **(** in between the text... it only works when textarea is **(** , but **not working** with   **abc(def**

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki did you see the Bhavin Solanki comment. :)

Comment: Check now please @innovation

Comment: Check now please @Bhavin Solanki

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

**UPDATED**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){$('#textarea').keyup(function(){

  if(($('#textarea').val() =="(" || $('#textarea').val().indexOf("(")>0) && $('#textarea').val().lastIndexOf("(") == $('#textarea').val().length-1 ){
      $('.tagBox').show();
  }else{
        $('.tagBox').hide();
  }
});
});
```

```css
.container{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0px auto;
    margin-top:30px;
}
.textarea_wrap{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position:relative;
}
.text{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    outline:none;
    border:1px solid #999999;
}
.tagBox{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="textarea_wrap">
        <textarea id="textarea" class="text"></textarea>
        <div class="tagBox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but .tagBox is opening any text i said when you write open parenthesis like `(`    then open `.tagBox` it means the `.tagBox` will open only when you write open parenthesis

Comment: @innovation i have check your accepted answer, but it is not perfect work. i have check his fiddle code too. But it wan't work if your write ( in between the text... it only works when textarea is ( , but not working with abc(def

Comment: also your answer is not perfectly working. For example your in your answer the .tagBox is never closing ? also when i write first open parenthesis the .tagBox not opening ?

Comment: again `.tagBox` never closing.

Comment: i see your updated answer but the `.tagBox` never closing.

Comment: Updated for the same too. plesae check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83077/discussion-between-bhavin-solanki-and-innovation).